# "Failed to execute 'postMessage'" error from Froogaloop via AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, iframe, angularjs-directive, vimeo, froogaloop

I wrote an AngularJS directive for vimeo videos with built in play/pause functionality using their froogaloop library.

It's works great! The only issue is that I get the following error when the page first loads.

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://player.vimeo.com') does not match the recipient
>   window's origin

Am I initializing the froogaloop object wrong in the directive?
Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

You can check it out the plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/GKWNk3LhX0MR3lhpfqyA

Comment: Sadly it's not something you can do anything about. Vimeo is attempting to communicate with its parent window with `postMessage(msg, 'http://vimeo.com/')` (note it's **not** using `(postMessage(msg, '*')`) and therefore that `postMessage` will only make sense to the parent window, not to your application. As such, it's only delivered when the iframe is embedded on Vimeo.com.

Comment: May thy humble self share the directive? Looking for a implementation myself! nvm, didn't see tha plnkr

Answer (score 6):

I recommend to execute the code in the `onLoad` event from `<iframe>`. Then you are ensured that the code will execute when iframe is ready for receiving messages.

There are plenty ways to do it:

- You can use jQuery if you already have it in your project: `$('iframe').load(callback)` or
- write an EventListener: `iframe_element.addEventListener('load', callback)`  or
- use plain onload callback: `iframe_element.onload = callback`.

Where `callback` is the method which uses Froogaloop.

But you have to know that some of those solutions might have some drawbacks on some old/MS browsers browsers.

Answer (score 2):

For me it looks like angularjs triggers Player API before actually rendering the iframe on the page. At least if I postpone scope.$watch it works fine:

```
$timeout(function() {
    scope.$watch('controlBoolean', function() {/* your code goes here */});
});
```